# Ocaml nested if without else

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Is it possible to have nested if without else statements. I wrote the following useless program to demonstrate nested ifs. How do I fix this so it's correct in terms of syntax. lines 5 and 6 gives errors.

```
let rec move_helper b sz r = match b with
    [] -> r
    |(h :: t) ->
        if h = 0 then
            if h - 1 = sz then h - 1 ::r
            if h + 1 = sz then h + 1 ::r
        else move_helper t sz r
;;

let move_pos b = 
    move_helper b 3 r
;;

let g = move_pos [0;8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1]
```

Comment: If you were not demonstrating nested ifs, you could match against (h, h-sz) – In real code, do not use nested ifs as pattern matching or mutually recursive functions do a *much* better job at structuring the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have `if` without `else` unless the result of the expression is of type `unit`. This isn't the case for your code, so it's not possible.

Here's an example where the result is `unit`:

```
let f x =
    if x land 1 <> 0 then print_string "1";
    if x land 2 <> 0 then print_string "2";
    if x land 4 <> 0 then print_string "4"
```

Comment: I tried enclosing both statements with (); earlier but then I receive a syntax error on line 7 (else recursive call)

Comment: Well, this is a different question. Generally speaking you need to be careful with parentheses when mixing nested `if`s and `let`. That is my experience. But your code reads like imperative code. That's the first obstacle to get past I suspect.

Comment: I removed the imperative code and replaced it with a recursive function. Only down side was one extra function and extra code. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that `if ... then` is an expression like any other.  If no `else` is present, it must be understood as `if ... then ... else ()` and thus has type `unit`.  To emphasize the fact that it is an expression, suppose you have two functions `f` and `g` of type, say, `int → int`.  You can write

```
(if test then f else g) 1
```

You must also understand that `x :: r` does *not* change `r` at all, it constructs a new list putting `x` in front of `r` (the tail of this list is shared with the list `r`).  In your case, the logic is not clear: what is the result when `h=0` but the two `if` fail?

```
let rec move_helper b sz r = match b with
  | [] -> r
  | h :: t ->
     if h = 0 then
       if h - 1 = sz then (h - 1) :: r
       else if h + 1 = sz then (h + 1) :: r
       else (* What do you want to return here? *)
     else move_helper t sz r
```

Answer (score -2):

When you have a if, always put an else. Because when you don't put an else, Java will not know if the case is true or false.